# React Native High Order Component for State Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, high-order-component

I'm trying to do a hoc for a state component in React Native with Typescript and I want to use it as a decorator. My type is defined below:

```
export function hoc<T extends ComponentClass>(target: any): T {
  return (target: any) =>
    class MyClass extends Component<any, any> {

    }
}
```

But I get the error `Type '(target: any) => typeof MyClass' is not assignable to type 'T'`

What should I change to make it correct with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type to represent that each returns the instance of the same type for which it was called:

```
class MyClass {

    public each<T extends MyClass>(callback: (item: T) => void): this {
        /* Loop through an array and apply the callback */
        return this;
    }

}

class Derived extends MyClass {
    foo: string;
}

let derived = new Derived;

derived = derived.each(() => {});
```

This might help you

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to implement extra methods I just want to mess with the types